# How do I move a field to a different table and maintain relationships?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I figure this has to be easy, I'm just not sure how to ask the question.

I have thousands of records I imported from a Excel Spreadsheet in a Microsoft Access table with a field that I want to extract into a new table. How do I move the data from the field in the existing table to a new table and maintain the relationships to the record?

The goal is to move the existing data from the one field into a new table that will have a one-to-many relationship with the existing parent table.

---

For example, in a table called `tblProperties` I have the following fields:

`Property_Address | Property_Owner | UtilityMeter_Number`

I want to maintain a history of utility meters on properties as they are replaced, so I want to move the `UtilityMeter_Number` field from `tblProperties` into a new table called `tblMeters` and create a one-many relationship between the two so I can have multiple meter records for each property record.

How do I move all the existing data from the `UtilityMeter_Number` field in `tblProperties` into `tblMeters`, and maintain the relationship?

---

What is what I'm trying to do called, and how do I do it?

Comment: Do you want to use autonumber primary key? Edit question to show sample data as a text table not image.

Comment: The key search term for the process you have described is [*Database Normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics) may help you with the task.

Comment: To be clear, as of right now I do not have any duplicate data in my tables. Going forward I want to be able to have multiple records in a new table whereas now I only have one datum per record in a field within in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

This is called normalizing data structure.

Use a SELECT DISTINCT query to create unique records. Use that dataset as source to create a new table. Something like:

`SELECT DISTINCT CustID, LName, FName, MName INTO Customers FROM Orders;`

Now delete unnecessary LName, FName, MName fields from Orders table.

Tables are related on the common CustID fields. An autonumber primary key is not utilized. If you do want a relationship on autonumber PK, then continue with following steps:

1. add an autonumber field in new table
2. create a number field in original table
3. run an UPDATE action SQL to populate new number field with autonumber value from new table - join tables on common CustID fields
4. also delete CustID field from original table